# Center Div on-top and in between two divs in Foundation Zurb

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I just started using Foundation and I like it a lot. I have a question.  I have a design that requires the logo to be horizontally centered, on-top and in between two full divs (see attached picture).

The code below is what I have which seems to work fine but doesn't re-size on screen changes and I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this when working with Foundation.

Is there a possible improvement that I could do to better integrate the logo into Foundation?  In other words is there a way to integrate the logo in a way that It re-sizes when the screen changes or this is my best option and I would need to re-size it manually for multiple screens?

HTML

```
<div class="row fullWidth">
     <div class="large-12 columns box"> 

              <img src="logo.png" class="logo">

      </div>
</div>

<div class="row fullWidth">
     <div class="large-12 columns box"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fullWidth {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
   position: relative;
}

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;// half-width of logo
    z-index: 20;
}


.box{
    background-color: #333;
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the logo, you can use negative `margin-top` as well, but you'll probably have to wrap the 2 outer divs with a new div.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="row fullWidth">
        <div class="large-12 columns box"> 
            <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row fullWidth">
        <div class="large-12 columns box"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.fullWidth {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
   // position: relative; // REMOVED
}

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;// half-width of logo
    margin-top: -100px;// half-height of logo
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the trick. I will manually resize it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to make it center

```
<div class="row fullWidth">
     <div class="large-12 columns box">
         <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="row fullWidth">
         <div class="large-12 columns box"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/xsxe3xx8/)**

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks a lot. I will resize it manually in one of the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the logo that doesn't resize? If so, try this:

```
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left: -100px;//half-width of logo
    z-index: 20;
}
```

The logo should be able to resize now.